# "Failed to push some refs to ..." in case of multiple remotes

Tags: git, github, drupal

Folks,

I have some weird issue, where I am having multiple remotes, but cant push to both. I have to rebase from that remote to push to that remote.

Setup

1. I have a remote on Github.com and another on Drupal.org
2. I am pushing to github.com, which goes well, however when I try to push same branch to drupal.org, I get "error: failed to push some refs to ...".
3. I now rebase my branch from Drupal.org, and then push. My code is pushed.
4. I now try to push to github.com and it fails with same error message, as above.
5. I now, rebase my branch from github.com and then push, I don't see the error anymore.
6. I now try to push again to Drupal.org and it fails again.

To me, it seems like there is some disparity where I cannot push to both remotes, without rebasing the branch.
What can be the possible problems and a possible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some change was made on one remote that didn't make it into the other. many reasons could cause this.

Every time you rebase the commit-id of the last few commits will change and that will put the repo out-of-sync with the other remote.

The simplest solution would be to force-push the repo to one of the remotes once...